# Add specific rows from dataGridView depending on search value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

Following issue: 
I have a datatable and a list which contains specific values.

```
routIds = col1Items.Distinct().ToList();
String searchValue = String.Empty;        
int rowIndex = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < routIds.Count; i++)
{
    searchValue = routIds[i];

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in form1.dataGridView5.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[form1.routingIdBox.Text].Value != null) // Need to check for null if new row is exposed
        {
            if (row.Cells[form1.routingIdBox.Text].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
            {
                rowIndex = row.Index;

                foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in form1.dataGridView5.Columns)
                    dtRout.Columns.Add(column.Name);

                for (int k = 0; k < form1.dataGridView5.Rows.Count; k++)
                {
                    dtRout.Rows.Add();
                    for (int j = 0; j < form1.dataGridView5.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        datTable.Rows[k][j] = form1.dataGridView5.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[j].Value;
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to search the first column from my datagridview and check if it matches a specific value (from my array - routIds). If yes then I want to add the whole row into a datatable but I don't know how this works exactly. Tried around but I get exceptions (specific row not found).

Comment: what is the underlying datasource of your `dataGridView5`? `DataTable`, `List<T>`, `BindingList`?

Comment: underlying datasource? it's a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a DataTable as your underlying DataSource. I would not iterate through the DataGridViewRows.

```
DataTable dataSource = dataGridView.DataSource as DataTable; // if it is a DataTable. If not, please specify in your question

// let's make a DataTable, which is a copy of your DataSource
DataTable dataTableFoundIds = new DataTable();
foreach (DataColumn column in dataSource.Columns)
     dataTableFoundIds.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);

// iterate through your routeIds
foreach (int id in routeIds)
{
    var row = dataSource.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(item => item["col1"].Equals(id)); // take the first row in your DataSource that matches your routeId
    if (row != null)
    {
        dataTableFoundIds.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray); // if we find something, insert the whole row of our source table
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**: if you want to find *all* occurances:

```
foreach (int id in routeIds)
{
    var rows = dataSource.AsEnumerable().Where(item => item["col1"].Equals(id)); // take all rows in your DataSource that match your routeId
    foreach(var row in rows)
    {
        dataTableFoundIds.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray); // if we find something, insert the whole row of our source table
    }
}
```

Comment: Although there are multiple values in a column the datatable stays empty... he doesn't find values. If you mean where the values from the datagridview come from: it's a database

Comment: is `dataSource = dataGridView.DataSource as DataTable` null?

Comment: No it isn't. It's filled with my GridViewData but somehow he doesn't find the value. Has it something to do with formation? The values in my array are converted string values. Originally they were integers (in the gridview)

Comment: try `item[form1.routingIdBox.Text].ToString().Equals(id.ToString())`

Comment: Ok know it works but he only copies the first row he finds... I would need every row with this value... There are five... I get only one